# Visual Studio- is it possible to copy hint?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I use Visual Studio 2010.

Hovering mouse pointer over method displays a hint.

Is it possible to copy this hint?

Thank you!

Comment: If you right-click and select "Go To Definition" then some or all of the tooltip may be in a comment that you can copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever field you want to copy the `hint`, Just press the `F12` or `Go To Definition` by right click over on that particular field , it will take you to the definition where you can get the text which is display as help tool-tip there.
Here is an example of `TextBox.Text` help text

```
// Summary:
// Gets or sets the text content of the System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label control.
```

Comment: It could be done this way but I prefer information given by a hint.